# execute unix command in java using sftp spring adapter

Tags: spring, adapter, sftp

Can someone please help me in how to execute unix command in java code using spring sftp adapter. I have made connection with that jar but don't know how to proceed further to execute unix command.

```
    package automation;

import java.io.InputStream;

import org.springframework.integration.channel.ChannelPurger;
import org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.Session;
import org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession;

import com.jcraft.jsch.*;


public class unixConnect {

    DefaultSftpSessionFactory dsftp;
    String input1 = "/****/****/file.dat";

    public DefaultSftpSessionFactory getDsftp() {
        return dsftp;
    }

    public void setDsftp(DefaultSftpSessionFactory dsftp) {
        this.dsftp = dsftp;
    }

    private Session sess;

    public void connect() {
        try {           
            sess = dsftp.getSession();
            String command = "ksh /home/***/exec " + input1;
            ---- This is the place how to execute the above command. 
            channel.setInputStream(null);           
            channel.setOutputStream(System.out);                                                                 
            ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand( command );               
            ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.out);
            channel.connect();                                                  
            InputStream input = channel.getInputStream();       

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

I have been looking into it to find an answer but not getting one. :(

Comment: What has SFTP got to do with executing commands in linux. Java already provides a way to execute linux commands, by Runtime library. Check that out.

Answer (score 0):

[SFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) is *SSH File Transfer Protocol*. You see the part "file transfer". There is no, command execution. You can transfer files, but you can't run anything. That is by definition.